# What is the AWS SDK equivalent of EC2's Run Command

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

AWS has a remote management capability for EC2.  I am looking for the same thing, but in the Ruby SDK.  I see it mentioned in the image below (See second to last sentence) but for the life of me, I can't figure out where this is in the SDK.  I have googled, looked through the docs and the API.  Is this just a cut and paste issue in the AWS documentation?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Command is part of the Simple Systems Manager Service (SSM).

[Here it is](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SSM.html) in the Ruby SDK.